# Why do JS modules load differently (async & sync) in a browser vs a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8

I recently read this: "ECMAScript 6 modules must work independently of whether the engine loads modules synchronously (e.g. on servers) or asynchronously (e.g. in browsers)."

Why would JS load asynchronously and synchronously, in a server vs a browser, respectively? Is this intentional?

Comment: On a server, module files are loaded from a file system (quickly), whereas in a browser, they are loaded over a network (slower, so it may be advantageous to load them asynchronously rather than let the page hang on a network fetch). Is that the answer you're looking for, or something more technical, e.g., what APIs or code is actually used to perform a load?

Comment: The server has a direct access to the file system and loads the modules directly from the hard drive. It does not need asynchronism because it's only limited by the hardware's speed anyway. On the other hand, browsers are vastly limited by the network speed. They can't afford to block the UI all the time because they're waiting for some file to load, so they have to do it asynchronously.

Comment: @JeremyThille is there a reason why servers don't load asynchronously as well? It seems like it wouldn't hurt. I'm trying to understand the tradeoff b/t the two.

Comment: @apsillers Yeah! Actually if you had the api's used to load the modules in each env. that would be extremely interesting

Comment: Servers load all the files and module off the app, then start the app. On the other hand, browsers download parts of a site at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servers prefer to import modules synchronously because they are loaded quickly from the file system. In general, synchronous code is easier to write and read. It's great in Node to be able to do:

```
var myModule = require("mymodule"),
    foo = require("foo");
myModule.doThing(foo);
```

instead of

```
require("mymodule", function(err, myModule) {
    require("foo", function(err, foo) {
        myModule.doThing(foo);
    });
});
```

Conversely, asynchronous code is often preferable in a browser, because a network load can take a longer time and synchronous execution blocks the UI. It's preferable to keep the browser's thread free to respond to the user (and display loading animations, etc.) while quietly loading modules in the background and asynchronously responding to their completion.